# Clonezilla breaks grub2 in fedora

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, clonezilla

I have Clonezilla (version 3.5.2-drbl1) packed with DRBL on my Ubuntu server. The image that I'm trying to deploy is a Windows 7 / Fedora 17 dual-booted image that uses Grub2 as a bootloader.

Saving images works fine, however, after restoring, I always get the "dreaded Grub boot", as in the only screen i get a single line saying `grub>`, after which I have to re-install grub2 via a rescue CD. The image i'm restoring boots wonderfully using grub2.

It gets pretty tedious having to re-install grub2 EVERYTIME I restore an image, and seeing as how I have multiple computers (around 30), it gets pretty time consuming.

I'm aware that Clonezilla should've fixed this issue already (as early as Clonezilla version 2.2x), so I don't know why I'm still getting this error.

Maybe I'm setting up Clonezilla wrong? I'm pretty close to tearing out my hair on this one, as it takes quite awhile to repair `grub2` on all the computers.

Comment: Which options are you using for image creating/restoring? Are you creating a whole disk image or separate partitions?

Comment: "*I'm aware that Clonezilla should've fixed this issue already*" Why? Did you report the problem to the developers of Clonezilla? --- Did you investigate what is corrupted in the GRUB boot process?

Comment: Can you give more info? For instance, is this an ms-dos partition table or a GPT? How about the pcs where you deploy this image: do they use the old BIOS (whether native or in legacy mode) or UEFI?

Comment: Are you using the proper Clonezilla options that save and restore GRUB2?

Comment: For creating the image and restoring, I'm using the default options (using Beginner mode in Clonezilla). I'm creating a whole disk image. The reason why I'm aware of the bugfix is due to the changelogs found on the Clonezilla site (I believe this issue was fixed with Clonezilla-Live v1.12). 

I'm using the legacy mode for booting into BIOS.

What options exist that allow Clonezilla to save and restore GRUB2?